# Coding style in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, coding-style

While this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734094/understanding-coding-style-in-angularjs) sums up the following three code styles:

1)

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', []);
function MainCrl($scope, $rootScope) {}
```

2)

```
angular.module('mainCtrl',[])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope)) { ... });
```

3)

```
angular.module('mainCtrl',[])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function(scope, rootScope)) { ... }]);
```

there's a fourth way i've seen [in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9MHigUZKEM&list=UUtbxTmNfHcXLV5nfpnQxFkw) that is very appealing for me

4)

```
var controllers = {}
controllers.mainCtrl = function($scope, $rootScope){ };
app.controller(controllers)
```

I am leaning towards continuing with 4), will it break if minified or are there any other drawbacks? Should i just go with 3) since it seems to be the standard way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, number 4 will break if minified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Option 1 pollutes global namespace and hinders minification and does not respect modules.
- Option 2 does not let you rename your injectables in controller signature.
- Option 4 pollutes global namespace, but it **is** minification-safe if you do it properly<sup>1</sup>.
- Option 3 lets you rename your injectables<sup>2</sup>, does respect modules, does not pollute global namespace, and does not require any extra work when minifying.

So my winner is option #3.

---

<sup>1</sup> Option 4 - minification-friendly version:

```all
var controllers = {};
controllers.mainCtrl = ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){ ... }];
app.controller(controllers);
```

<sup>2</sup> Renaming injectables:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope, User){ ... }]);
```

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation: Go with option 3, for three reasons:

1. It is (IMHO) the most widely adopted one.
2. You have no problems with minification (and this is the only option where this is true).
3. It works best with modules.